# How to make Visual Studio aware that he should take the new version of a referenced DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, compilation

I have a solution with two projets. One referencing the other. When I make changes in the second one and compile it, the first one doesn't seem to be aware of it. As it is linked to the old version of it.

Is there a way to tell VS2012 to check if the referenced DLL files have changed since the last time he copied them on his local folder?

Comment: Do they have the same output folder?

Comment: Currenlty, if I quit VS and relaunch the solution then it works...

Comment: Are you compiling the entire solution every time?

Comment: The compilation directory is l:/bin and the path to the DLL is the same.

Comment: No indeed. I just complie the underlying DLL. And I wanted to see new methods, etc... and the first one.

Comment: Usually, this happens automatically... Hard to tell from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong. It was the Reference Path that contains slashes "/" instead of back-slashes "\". It seems that i worked partially whith that kind of path, but not always.

[image]

PS : *I enter this in case this could help someone in the future.*

Answer (score 0):

When you reference the second project, make sure that you reference it as a "Project Reference."  That tells VS to update the reference when that project changes.  If you use a DLL reference, it assumes that the reference is to an external DLL, and so it expects you to maintain the versions.

Comment: "Project Reference" instead of what?

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, when you right-click the references for the project and select "Add a Reference," a dialog will pop up.  That dialog has tabs to allow you to select the type of reference.  One of those tabs is "Projects." That is the one you want to use, not "Browse."